# Executing command using variable in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

```
@ECHO OFF
set "str1=cd"
set "str2=%~dp0"
set "str5=CPCE Client\EfileServiceClient""
set "str4=%str1% %str2%%str5%"
Echo.%str4%
```

i want to execute the command which is existed in variable **"str4"** how to execute it....

Comment: If str5 didn't have a space in it, I'd recommend simply using `%str4%` by itself as a command.

Answer (score 1):

Simply type `%str4%` in the command prompt or state it in a batch file to execute its value as a command line.

However, there are some issues in your code:

- there is a closing `"` too much at the `str5` assignment, which must be removed; otherwise, the value of `str5` equaled `CPCE Client\EfileServiceClient"`;
- there is a space in the value of `str5`; spaces must be handled correctly, as you would type the command in the command prompt; arguments with spaces should be enclosed within `""`;
  (actually, for the `cd` command (in `str1`), spaces do not cause any problems, so it would also work without `""`; however, for most commands, spaces most probably *will* cause troubles)

The following adapted code will work:

```
@echo off
set "str1=cd"
set "str2=%~dp0"
set "str5=CPCE Client\EfileServiceClient"
set "str4=%str1% "%str2%%str5%""
%str4%
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
echo %str4% > temp.cmd
call temp.cmd
del temp.cmd
```

Although I think it would make more sense not to add cd to the string and do this instead:

```
cd %str4%
```